# How to stop stored procs from whining about a missing column that I am about to delete in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, search, stored-procedures

I am deleting a column from one of the frequently used tables in my database. 
Last time I did this errors started to crawl up from all sorts of stored procs that I had long forgotten existed; complaining about the missing column. (only when that stored proc was called)

so, I dont want to get winded up with these things again,  I want to make sure all stored procs are free of that column before I actually delete it.

What is the best way to search through all stored procs (and I have quite a lot of them) and remove the reference to that column?

I tried to find an option in the menu to do this but I did not find anything very obvious to do this.

any help, (other than telling me to go through them all one by one) is appreciated.
ps: of course, doesnt mean that I will depreciate your comment if you do tell me. I will only downvote :P
(nah, just kidding!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script.  It will also return triggers. If many tables has column with the same name you can add tale name to the where too. This script works on MSSQL 2000, 2005. I haven't tested it on 2008, but it should work fine too.

```
SELECT o.name
FROM sysobjects o
    INNER JOIN syscomments c ON o.id = c.id
WHERE c.text like '%column_name%'
```

Edit: If you want to filter it only to store procedures add `AND type ='P'` to the where clause

Comment: +1 only caveat here is that you hope you dont have queries floating around in your code :-)

Comment: This is perfect thanks! it listed out all stored procs, (and I am not using any triggers.. yet!) thanks a ton!

Comment: @In Sane: nah, I dont have ANY querries in my c#, I do 100% of work in stored procs (or atleast as much as possible) and then I have Data access layer in my project to seperate things.. so i am, for once, a happy coder!

Answer (score 3):

To add to the various TSQL solutions, there is a free tool from Red Gate that integrates into SSMS: [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm)

Comment: wow!! +1 for this tool.. I am using Red Gate's Data Compare and SQL Compare (7) and they are amazing.. and this tool being free, wow. thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Red Gate Software's [SQL Prompt 5](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) has a couple of new features that might be useful in this situation:

- **Column Dependencies**: hover over a column name in a script and up pops a window containing a list of all the objects that use that column
- **Find Invalid Objects**: show objects across the database that can't be used, often because they use columns that have been deleted

You can download a 14-day free trial to see if the tool would be useful for you.

Paul Stephenson
SQL Prompt Project Manager
Red Gate Software

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** sorry, my bad. here's the code for searching within the stored procedure's code

The following stored procedure should be able to list all the stored procedures whose text contain the desired string (so, place your column name in it and fire away):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Find_Text_In_SP
@StringToSearch varchar(100) 
AS 
   SET @StringToSearch = '%' +@StringToSearch + '%'
   SELECT Distinct SO.Name
   FROM sysobjects SO (NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN syscomments SC (NOLOCK) on SO.Id = SC.ID
   AND SO.Type = 'P'
   AND SC.Text LIKE @stringtosearch
   ORDER BY SO.Name
GO
```

Usage:

```
exec Find_Text_In_SP 'desired_column_name'
```

Source [here](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/storedprocfinds.html)

Comment: this will only search procedure names

Comment: This will create a new stored proc in the database that i will have to delete everytime i finish running it right?

Comment: I'd leave the stored procedure there for future usage; if you don't want to, then simply use the code for the SELECT command itself (everything from "SELECT Distinct SO.Name" to "Order by SO.Name" - don't' forget to replace "@stringtosearch" with '%desired_column_name%')

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dependence option for that table to find the Dependent object or list of Procedure or function which are depend on this table.
Use below script

```
sp_depends 'TableName'
```

another option is create script for that column containing but that will filter all the text in the procedure or function.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MS SQL later than version 2000, it's better to search [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) rather than [sys.syscomments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx), since syscomments only hold records of nvarchar(4000), and the text you are looking for may be split into two records.

So while you can use a query like this from MSDN

```
SELECT sm.object_id, OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id) AS object_name, o.type, o.type_desc, sm.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules AS sm
JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE sm.definition like '%' + @ColumnName + '%'
ORDER BY o.type;
```

you should be aware that this search finds *any* procedure containing that text, regardless of whether it is an actual column name and which table the column belongs to.